# How to instantiate Element from String in JPBC library?

Tags: java, json, string, biginteger

I've been working with JPBC for a while.

Now I'm stuck in one little problem. I need to receive a String representation (from JSON) of a generated element from G1 group. So I randomly generated (using newRandomElement()) this element g.

```
Field<?> G1 = pairing.getG1();
Element g = G1.newRandomElement().getImmutable()
```

However, g cannot be converted to BigInteger (Exception: Cannot convert to BigInteger) because at some point it contains "401329,3521518".

The receiver gets a String representation of g and then has to instantiate a new Element but it's not possible to do that using a Big Integer as parameter (as I just told you) and there's no way to do it using a String as parameter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you just have to use Base64 encoding and decoding like:

```
String s = Base64.encodeBytes(g.toBytes());
...
Element g2 = G1.newElementFromBytes(Base64.decode(s));
```